# How to implement add R.raw.custom_sound value to entryValues of listpreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, settings, android-preferences

I wanna implement custom sounds in Settings. For this i'm using ListPreference. As we know

android:entries - The human-readable array to present as a list.

android:entryValues - The array to find the value to save for a preference when an entry from entries is selected.

```
<ListPreference
        android:key="sound_income"
        android:title="@string/sound_income"
        android:entries="@array/sound_income"
        android:entryValues="@array/sound_income"
        android:summary="Cutting through"/>


<string-array name="sound_income">
    <item>Cutting through</item>
    <item>Don don</item>
    <item>Oringz pack nine</item>
    <item>Oringz pack</item>
</string-array>
```

Right now shared preference saves above texts but in order to play sound i need to get resId like this R.raw.cutting_through. The question is that how can i implement android:entryValues="@array/sound_income_values" string array to create sound`s int value not their names?

Comment: Is it possible to implement like:                                                      <string-array name="sound_income">
    <item>R.raw.sound1</item>
    <item>R.raw.sound2</item>
    <item>R.raw.sound3</item>
    <item>R.raw.sound4</item>
</string-array>